# Parsing in scala/Java

Tags: scala, parsing

I am writing a Parser in scala and got stuck at this point:

```
  private def expression : Parser[Expression] = cond | variable | integer | liste | function

  private def cond : Parser[Expression] = "if" ~ predicate ~ "then" ~ expression ~ "else" ~ expression ^^ {case _~i~_~t~_~el => Cond(i,t,el)}

  private def predicate: Parser[Predicate] =  identifier ~ "?" ~ "(" ~ repsep(expression, ",") ~ ")" ^^{case n~_~_~el~_ => Predicate(n,el)}

  private def function: Parser[Expression] = identifier ~ "(" ~ repsep(expression, ",") ~ ")" ^^{case n~_~el~_ => Function(n,el)}

  private def liste: Parser[Expression] = "[" ~ repsep(expression, ",") ~ "]"  ^^ {case _~ls~_ => Liste(ls)}

  private def variable: Parser[Expression] = identifier ^^ {case v => Variable(v)}

  def identifier: Parser[String]   = """[a-zA-Z0-9]+""".r       ^^ { _.toString }

  def integer: Parser[Integer]    = num ^^ { case i => Integer(i)}

  def num: Parser[String] = """(-?\d*)""".r ^^ {_.toString}
```

My problem is that when it comes to an "expression" the Parser does not always takes the right way. Like if its `funk(x,y)` it tries to parse it like a variable ant not like a function.

Any idea?

Comment: change order in `expression`. try function  to put before variable.

Comment: I think the ||| operation could solve it?

Comment: What does this have to with [tag:java]?

Answer (score 0):

Change order of parsers in your `expression` parser - put `function` before `variable` and after `cond`. In general, when you compose parsers using alternative `A | B`, then parser `A` shouldn't be able to parse input that is prefix of input parsable by parser `B`.